# Is it possible to remove a JSON array element by value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json, array, json-path

In MySQL, it's possible to remove an array element by index:

```sql
SELECT JSON_REMOVE('["a", "b", "c"]', '$[1]') `result`;
+------------+
| result     |
+------------+
| ["a", "c"] |
+------------+
```

Is it possible to remove by value instead - in this case the element(s) matching the string `"b"`?

Based on the documentation, it's possible to find the index via `JSON_SEARCH` and then passing it to `JSON_REMOVE`, however, I was wondering if there's an expression/function to do it in a single function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of writing this, MySQL has no dedicated JSON function to allow you to remove a JSON array element by its value.  You have to use [whatever functions are available](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-function-reference.html) to come up with a custom expression to achieve your goal.  Depending on the requirements, you might even want to create a custom function.

More specifically, if the requirement is to **remove the first occurrence** of a value, then one way to do it is like this:

```
SET @value := 'b';

SELECT
  j.j AS before_remove
, JSON_REMOVE(
    j.j
  , JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_SEARCH(
        j.j
      , 'one'
      , @value
      )
    )
  ) AS after_remove
FROM
  (SELECT '["a", "b", "c", "b"]') AS j (j)
;
```

Returns:

| before_remove | after_remove |
| --- | --- |
| ["a", "b", "c", "b"] | ["a", "c", "b"] |

`JSON_SEARCH` returns a quoted path to the value found (`"$[1]"` in this case), `JSON_UNQUOTE` removes the quotes (yielding `$[1]`), following which the path can be fed to `JSON_REMOVE`.

If you want to **remove an arbitrary occurrence of a value**, the expression becomes somewhat more complex:

```
SET @value := 'b';
SET @occurrence := 2;

SELECT
  j.j AS before_remove
, JSON_REMOVE(
    j.j
  , JSON_UNQUOTE(
      JSON_EXTRACT(
        JSON_SEARCH(
          j.j
        , 'all'
        , @value
        )
      , CONCAT('$[', @occurrence - 1, ']')
      )
    )
  ) AS after_remove
FROM
  (SELECT '["a", "b", "c", "b"]') AS j (j)
;
```

Output:

| before_remove | after_remove |
| --- | --- |
| ["a", "b", "c", "b"] | ["a", "b", "c"] |

In this case, depending on the number of entries found, `JSON_SEARCH` may return a JSON array of paths rather than a single path.  Before applying `JSON_UNQUOTE`, therefore, we need to extract the specific path from the array matching the required occurrence, for which we can use `JSON_EXTRACT`.  The `CONCAT` expression returns the corresponding path for `JSON_EXTRACT` (and then we get a path to use with `JSON_REMOVE` – yes, I know, it is a little confusing).

Finally, in order to be able to **remove all occurrences**, you need to loop over the results of the path array returned by `JSON_SEARCH` and either sequentially run `JSON_REMOVE` with each path or somehow build and evaluate a single dynamic `JSON_REMOVE` expression including all paths.  Either way you need to do this in a [custom-created function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html).

Alternatively you could try solving this in a set-based manner, for instance using the [`JSON_TABLE` function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table) to turn the path array – output of `JSON_SEARCH` – into a row set, one path per row, and then using a [recursive CTE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html) on the set, applying each path one by one and getting the last result as the final JSON.

The options are there and I am leaving the solution as an exercise for the reader.  I will only add that both queries above are available online [at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8bd9ee845decc308d02847700ca5e1df).

Answer (score 0):

Just use json_remove as below:

SET @j = '["a", ["b", "c", "d"], "e"]';
SELECT JSON_REMOVE(@j, '$[1][2]');

or

SET @j = '{"e1": "a", "e2": ["b", "c", "d"], "e3": "e"}';
select JSON_REMOVE(@j, '$."e2"[1]');

Comment: This is removal by index, not by value.

Answer (score -1):

I had a syntax error with the above query, but it really helped me sort it out. This worked for me.

```sql
UPDATE role AS r 
SET permissions = JSON_REMOVE(
  r.permissions,
  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(r.permissions, 'one', 'my_key'))
) 
WHERE r.custom = true
```